# Grunt/grunt-karma - limit maximum task duration?

Tags: unit-testing, gruntjs, karma-runner

Is it possible to somehow set how long any Grunt task can take? And if the time exceeds the limit, it would fail the task? Something like "abort on stuck" feature?

I'm using grunt-karma to run unit tests and it sometimes hangs on CI server for couple of hours due to some networking issues (probably npm install did not install all dependencies...). If this time limit is not supported by Grunt as such, is there any grunt-karma specific option to use?